# How build a conversation handler with CllbackQueryHandler in it

Tags: python-telegram-bot

*NB: I use version 12 of python-telegram-bot package.*

I would like to build a conversation handler: when  a user chooses \charts command, the bot shows them an inline list of choices, and depending on their choice, return them a chart.

```
charts_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('chart', chart_start)],
    states={
        ChartChoices.choosing_user: [CallbackQueryHandler(
            individual_chart,
            pass_user_data=True)
        ],
    },
    fallbacks=[done_handler],
)
```

But if I do not set `per_message=False` then it results in this error:

```
If 'per_message=False', 'CallbackQueryHandler' will not be tracked for every message.
```

If I do set `per_message=True`, then it results in the error:

```
If 'per_message=True', all entry points and state handlers                                      
must be 'CallbackQueryHandler', since no other handlers have a message context.
```

So it seems that the only way to build a conversation handler with CallBackQueryHandler (or in other words to show inline keyboard during chat) is to set all handlers to CallbackQueryHandler. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is not an error, it's a warning you can safely ignore: `If 'per_message=False', 'CallbackQueryHandler' will not be tracked for every message.`

Second, you don't need a `ConversationHandler` for described use case. Example user interaction:

`User: /charts
Bot: 
Here is the list of available charts:
Bar chart 1 /chart_1
Bar chart 2 /chart_2
Pie chart /chart_3`

And this kind of flow you can implement with simple `MessageHandler` and `Filters`

[Docs: MessageHandler](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.messagehandler.html)

[Docs: Filters](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#module-telegram.ext.filters)

Namely you can use the [regex filter](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.regex).

`ConversationHandler` is useful when you need a multistep iteraction with the user (like filling out a long form step by step). If you can identify user requests by other means, like generated commands, inline buttons, message text — prefer doing it this way.